# Assign int value to image for compare with higher value wins (card game)

Tags: java, android, playing-cards

I'm a rookie programmer and I'm trying to develop a card game based on higher wins.
The problem is, I don't know how to assign int values to cards to compare.
Let's say there are 46 cards, each one has a different value, something like:

```
int peter = 19; 
int jack = 26; 
int martin = 22; 
//...and so on
```

There are two players, each one has four randomly generated cards (I did it like this, so I can cast  flip animation on each one, it's a bit clumsy but it works)

```
    //Assign my cards
    TypedArray my_cards = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.mycards);
    final Random random5 = new Random();
    final Random random6 = new Random();
    final Random random7 = new Random();
    final Random random8 = new Random();

    //Generate random indexes for my cards
    int RandomCard5 = random5.nextInt(my_cards.length());
    int RandomCard6 = random6.nextInt(my_cards.length());
    int RandomCard7 = random7.nextInt(my_cards.length());
    int RandomCard8 = random8.nextInt(my_cards.length());
    //Generate my cards from RandomCard
    int drawableCard5 = my_cards.getResourceId(RandomCard5,-1);
    int drawableCard6 = my_cards.getResourceId(RandomCard6,-1);
    int drawableCard7 = my_cards.getResourceId(RandomCard7,-1);
    int drawableCard8 = my_cards.getResourceId(RandomCard8,-1);
    //Deal my cards
    card1.setImageResource(drawableCard5);
    card2.setImageResource(drawableCard6);
    card3.setImageResource(drawableCard7);
    card4.setImageResource(drawableCard8);
```

As you can see, I'm using typedArray (Not sure if it's a good idea for this).
For the enemy cards it's the same.
After choosing a card for a fight (confirm button), it's transfered to other ImageView (fightcard1) and an enemy card is randomly choosen from those four random cards and transfered to ImageView (fightcard2).

Now I need to compare those cards (let's say those cards will have values 19 and 24).
The compare function shouldn't be a problem, but I have no idea how to assign those specific int values to specific cards.
Is there a way I could do this with my current "garbage" code, or is there a better and easier way with some/complete rewriting?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need a different `Random` instance for each value you generate. You just need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best i think for you to create an object called Card

```
public class Card{
    private int cardValue;

    public Card(int cardValue){

        this.cardValue = cardValue;
    }

    public int GetCardValue(){
        return cardValue;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what other information you want to store on this card but it can easily be added by adding it to the constructor as was done with `cardValue` on the `Card` method. This will then allow you to store the `Card` object and when you want to compare them, you would call `card1.GetCardValue()` which will return the value in the `cardValue` variable. This will allow you to do the comparison which you are trying to do.

you would create a Card object with

```
Card card = new Card(5); // this would set the cards value to 5.
```

If you have any more questions feel free to comment an ill help you out as i am not entirely sure what other information about the card you need to store.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Sean Powell 
For now, I just keep only one value. But now I'm bit confused, how to assign (connect) the cardValue to the items in my resource file. Does this mean, I have to create all cards as objects from the class and then do random dealing of the cards according to this? 
Let's say that in resource file is image peter_card. I want this card to have value 19. According to your advice I would create object: Card peter = new Card(19);
How to connect this with item in res file? Is it even possible? Or should I do the whole dealing thing differently? Thank you.

Comment: @Sandman add another variable to the Card object either called image where you sore the loaded image or called imageSrc where you store the path to the image. Then you can have a list of the cards like `List<Card> cards = new List<Card>` and deal randomly from this list, then when you want to display the card, you load the image resource from the Card object or you use the path on the card object to load the image depending on which method you use.

Comment: I though so. Thank you very much for this, I'll try it this way.