# Assign random class object (image) to ImageView

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a card game, based on higher wins.
From my first question here [assign int value to image for compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433217/assign-int-value-to-image-for-compare-with-higher-value-wins-card-game) I've rewritten my code but now I'm stuck on randomization of cards and assignment to ImageView.

I have a class card.

```
public class Card{
private int cardValue;
@DrawableRes
private int image;

public Card(int cardValue, @DrawableRes int image){
    this.cardValue = cardValue;
    this.image = image;
}

public int getCardValue()
{
    return cardValue;
}
@DrawableRes
public int getCardImage()
{
    return image;
}

//Cards
Card ash = new Card(20, R.drawable.ash_card);
Card atlas = new Card(23, R.drawable.atlas_card);
Card banshee = new Card(14, R.drawable.banshee_card);
and so on....
```

In MainActivity:
I have array of this cards:

```
//Creating array of the cards
ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now I need to randomize four cards from this array and assign each one to IV.

```
 final Random random1 = new Random();
 //Generate random indexes for cards
 int RandomCard1 = random1.nextInt(cards.size());
 int RandomCard2 = random1.nextInt(cards.size());
 int RandomCard3 = random1.nextInt(cards.size());
 int RandomCard4 = random1.nextInt(cards.size());
 //Generate the card from RandomCard
 Card drawableCard1 = cards.get(RandomCard1);
 Card drawableCard2 = cards.get(RandomCard2);
 Card drawableCard3 = cards.get(RandomCard3);
 Card drawableCard4 = cards.get(RandomCard4);
```

I'm using this, because I have flip animation for each card (maybe there is a better way to do it, but it works for me). So now I just need to assign a card to IV, but this won't work.

```
//Deal my cards
card1.setImageResource(drawableCard1);
card2.setImageResource(drawableCard2);
card3.setImageResource(drawableCard3);
card4.setImageResource(drawableCard4);
```

I can't use setImageResource for class object. I've been stuck here for days, trying to figure it out but with no luck. Should I do randomizing differently (f.e. with Collections.shuffle?). Or is there any way how to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have two different problems:
the simplest is that your cards are not showing since `setImageResource` requires the `int` representing the resource id as parameter, you'll just need to call:

```java
//Deal my cards
card1.setImageResource(drawableCard1.getCardImage());
card2.setImageResource(drawableCard2.getCardImage());
card3.setImageResource(drawableCard3.getCardImage());
card4.setImageResource(drawableCard4.getCardImage());
```

Now if the UI is correctly set up you'll see the images.
The second problem (I don't know if it's intended behavior) is that some cards could be given repeatedly, since the algorithm just generates a number within the bound and repetitions could occur.
A possible solution is, as you suggested, using `Collections.shuffle()` on the deck at the beginning so that it would simulate the initial deck shuffling and start dealing the cards in the exact order in which they are contained in your shuffled deck.

**How to deal cards**
Currently, if we consider our deck to be the entire `List` of `Card` objects, the way in which the dealer is picking the next card to give is by choosing a random card in any position of the deck (list) and put it on the table (for example). This idea could be extended by removing the picked card from the deck (which is something that at the moment is not implemented), but the dealing style wouldn't represent what happens in reality.
**Solution**
The solution would be shuffling the cards at the beginning of the game (`Collections.shuffle()`) and start picking the card in the exact order in which they are contained in the list. In fact, since it's already shuffled, the dealer can pick the `0-th`, `1-st`, `2-nd`
etc. card and put them on the table (or give them to the players). The `Random` object, in this case, wouldn't be needed. A simple cycle could be implemented to select the next card the dealer will pick.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Sadly, after this my app is crashing. I discoverd, that problem is on this line: 
int RandomCard5 = random2.nextInt(cards.size());
I got an error IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive, which means that cards.size is empty. I rechecked all objects and everything should return correct image. Now I'm confused, why it returns zero, if I'm missing soomething in my Card class or in MainActivity.

Comment: Hi @Sandman, I tested your code yesterday and it was working with this fix. Did you add the Cards to the List before generating the random integers?

Comment: Damm, I shouldn't be coding, when feeling sic. What do you mean by adding Cards to the List? I know it's a stupid question, but I thought that when ArrayList is defined: ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>(); it takes the objects I have created in Card class (Card ash = new Card(20, R.drawable.ash_card); and so on...) to it. I have to add it manually in MainActivity? Because something like cards.add(ash); is not working. I'm missing something obvious right? 
Thank you.

Comment: When you create a `new ArrayList` that is completely empty, so everything you need must be added to it. The `Card` between `<>` means that it will contain objects of type `Card`. Now to add `ash` to the list you'll have to do `list.add(ash)`. You can do it in MainActivity or anywhere is suitable. Maybe adding is not working because you've to instantiate the objects in the same class in which you're going to add them. Try to create the cards in MainActivity. I suggest searching on the Internet about how to use data structures in Java, since they're useful for what you're doing. No problem.

Comment: Damm, you're right, the objects has to be in MainActivity, it works now, thanks again!

Comment: I just remebered the second issue you mentioned, so I'm gonna ask - how to solve possible repetitions of the cards with the `Collections.shuffle()` ? Does it have to be called in specific place? How you meant start deailng in exact order? 
Thanks again.

Comment: I've added something about this in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and patience!