# Compare two class objects in card game

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm developing a card game. From some of my previous questions ([Assign int value to image fro compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433217/assign-int-value-to-image-for-compare-with-higher-value-wins-card-game) and [Assign random class object image to imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632158/assign-random-class-object-image-to-imageview) I'm finally stuck on the main part - compare logic.
I have two classes - Card and EnemyCard.

```
public class Card{
private int cardValue;
@DrawableRes
private int image;

public Card(int cardValue, @DrawableRes int image){
    this.cardValue = cardValue;
    this.image = image;
}

public int getCardValue()
{
    return cardValue;
}
@DrawableRes
public int getCardImage()
{
    return image;
}
```

EnemyCard class is the same, only it's name is different.
In MainActivity I have objects, arrays, and random dealing.

```
 //Creating objects
 Card ash = new Card(20, R.drawable.ash_card);
 Card atlas = new Card(23, R.drawable.atlas_card);
 Card banshee = new Card(14, R.drawable.banshee_card);
 ...
 //Creating array of my the cards
 cards = new ArrayList<>();
 cards.add(ash);
 cards.add(atlas);
 cards.add(banshee);
 ...
 final Random random2 = new Random();
 //Generate random indexes for my cards
 int RandomCard5 = random2.nextInt(cards.size());
 int RandomCard6 = random2.nextInt(cards.size());
 int RandomCard7 = random2.nextInt(cards.size());
 int RandomCard8 = random2.nextInt(cards.size());
 //Generate my cards from RandomCard
 Card drawableCard5 = cards.get(RandomCard5);
 Card drawableCard6 = cards.get(RandomCard6);
 Card drawableCard7 = cards.get(RandomCard7);
 Card drawableCard8 = cards.get(RandomCard8);
```

Again it's the same for the EnemyCard class, only with some slight differences in the cards' names.
Then I assign the cards to IV.

```
//Deal my cards
card1.setImageResource(drawableCard5.getCardImage());
card2.setImageResource(drawableCard6.getCardImage());
card3.setImageResource(drawableCard7.getCardImage());
card4.setImageResource(drawableCard8.getCardImage());
```

Again the same for enemy cards. After this comes my clumsy design.
When you click on the IV (f.e. **card1**), the card is "transferred to other IV called **expanded_card** (this simulates larger view of the card), and a **confirm** button appears. If you confirm the card, it's transferred to the last IV called **fight_card** (this is the clumsy part).
After this is also chosen random enemy card. I did this creating array of those four enemy cards and then using switch-case and *Collections.shuffle()* to assign one random enemy card to an IV called **fight_card2** (yeah, this is totally clumsy)

```
//Enemy fight cards
enemy_deck_cards = new ArrayList<>();
enemy_deck_cards.add(10);
enemy_deck_cards.add(11);
enemy_deck_cards.add(12);
enemy_deck_cards.add(13);
//Logic for enemy card for fight
public void assignImage(int card, ImageView image){
    switch (card){
        case 10:
            image.setImageDrawable(enemy_card1.getDrawable());
            enemy_card1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            enemy_card2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            enemy_card3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            enemy_card4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 11:
            image.setImageDrawable(enemy_card2.getDrawable());
            enemy_card2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            enemy_card1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            enemy_card3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            enemy_card4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 12:
            image.setImageDrawable(enemy_card3.getDrawable());
            enemy_card3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            enemy_card1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            enemy_card2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            enemy_card4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case 13:
            image.setImageDrawable(enemy_card4.getDrawable());
            enemy_card4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            enemy_card1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            enemy_card2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            enemy_card3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}
```

Setting visibility is for simulating that a card is chosen from the deck.
Lastly, there is the confirm button, where are the main parts (and some other, not so important stuff).

```
//Assign cards to fight
assignImage(enemy_deck_cards.get(0),fight_card2);
fight_card.setImageDrawable(expanded_card.getDrawable());
```

If you made it this far and haven't fainted from this horror code, I admire you. Now comes the logic and I'm stuck here.
How to achieve that the chosen cards in IVs (**fight_card** and **fight_card2**) are compared?
I tried something like this:

```
   public void fightLogic(Card fightCard, EnemyCard fightCard2, TextView message){

        if (fightCard.getCardValue() > fightCard2.getCardValue()){
            message.findViewById(R.id.message);
            message.setText(R.string.YOUWIN);
        } else
        if (fightCard.getCardValue() < fightCard2.getCardValue()){
            message.findViewById(R.id.message);
            message.setText(R.string.YOULOST);
        } else
        if (fightCard.getCardValue() == fightCard2.getCardValue()){
            message.findViewById(R.id.message);
            message.setText(R.string.DRAW);
        }
}
```

But this obviously won't work. I don't see any way how to do this, if it's even possible with my horror code. If anybody has any piece of advice (and critique for sure) regarding the logic or even design, I'd be truly grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: If `EnemyCard` is exactly the same as `Card` why is it a different class instead of just a new object?  For example the method call would be `fightLogic(Card playerCard, Card enemyCard, TextView message)`.  Or if it has _most_ of the same functionality, you can use inheritance on `Card`. Also I don't see why comparing the card values would not work if they are just integers as shown.

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice with the classes. I know that comparing should work, only my point it how to call it when confim is pressed, because each time, there would be different cards in those two IVs. Yes, I could call something like `fightLogic(drawableCard5, drawable card1, message)` but that only works for those specific cards. I need to compare those two cards, which are seen (after confim is pressed) in `fight_card` and `fight_card2`.